# How to retrieve Parcelable objects in fragments correctly?

Tags: android, android-fragments, parcelable, android-safe-args

> In a fragment,
>
> ```
>    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
>     super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
>         var args = arguments
>         args?.getParcelable<Jar>("jar").let {
>             viewModel.setJar(it as Jar)
>         }
>         setObservers()
>    }
> ```
>
> Above code is working fine but,
>
> ```
> args?.getParcelable<Jar>("jar").let {
>           viewModel.setJar(it as Jar)
>        }
> ```
>
> is deprecated. So I tried
>
> ```
> args?.getParcelable("jar", Jar::class.java).let {
>     viewModel.setJar(it as Jar)
> }
> ```
>
> But its throwing error.
>
> java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No virtual method getParcelable(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Class;)Ljava/lang/Object; in class Landroid/os/Bundle; or its super classes (declaration of 'android.os.Bundle' appears in /system/framework/framework.jar!classes2.dex)
>
> Parcelable Object:
>
> ```
> @Parcelize data class Jar(
>
> @field:SerializedName("id")
> val id: String? = null,
>
> @field:SerializedName("name")
> val name: String? = null,
>
> @field:SerializedName("description")
> val description: String? = null,
>
> @field:SerializedName("imageUrl")
> val imageUrl: String? = null,
>
> ) : Parcelable
> ```
>
> ```
> nav_version = "2.5.3" 
>
> dependencies {
>  classpath "androidx.navigation:navigation-safe-args-gradle-plugin:$nav_version"
>
> plugins { 
>     id 'kotlin-parcelize'
> ```
>
> Can someone help me, how to retrieve Parcelable objects correctly with latest way and correct way.

Comment: Able to retrive object by 

 `private val args: JarContributionsFragmentArgs by navArgs()

         var jar = args.jar'`